# determine whether given number is integer without using PHP functions

Tags: php

In interview I have been asked this question check whether given value is integer or not without using php functions, I have tried `var_dump()`, `gettype()` and other things but interviewer denied using php function, is there any way to determine whether given input is integer ?

Comment: `var_dump((int)$num === $num);`

Comment: That uses 5 functions.....

Comment: Frankly, it seems a completely pointless interview question... Teneff's answer appears to fit, but I can't think of a time you'd ever actually do that? So maybe it's just as well.

Comment: I have modified question and it's more clear, kindly review the question again for answer.

Answer (score 3):

The plus operator will return an integer, so without using functions you can check it like this

```
if ($input === +$input ) {
    /// Is int
}
else {
    // not an int
}
```

Comment: Good catch - works with floats too.

Comment: This will emit a "*Warning: A non-numeric value encountered*" warning though if the value is non-numeric, like a string. But logically it works!

Answer (score 1):

The only best possible solution to this question is checking whether the number is having any decimal/dot(.) in it or not.
If the number have decimal/dot than its considered as non-integer else number is integer.
So, by using simple for loop and following above mentioned approach, would help to get result without using any predefined/in-built function of PHP.